# session not working

Tags: c#

I am using SQL express 2008 and visual studio 2010.

I made a simple login form using session. I want that if the session is null the user shouldn't be able to go to the desired page. I have written the following code:

```
public void btnsubmit_CLICK(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text =="admin" && TXTID.Text =="admin")
    {
        Session["user"] = "admin";
        Response.Redirect("generate_report.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "user name Or password is not correct!"; 
    }
```

NEXT PAGE:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["user"] != "admin")
    {     
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

It is working fine if I use it locally but when I load it on the client server it doesn't work at all. Why is so?

Comment: Is you client server a web farm using in process session state?

Comment: I can't comment on the problem you are experiencing, but you really should not be rolling your own auth system. AspNetMembershipProvider ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx ) gives you everything you need for free.

Comment: "*id doesn't work at all*" doesn't mean anything. Please precise the error(s).

Comment: no error is coming but code is not working!

Comment: What is the behaviour? Does "not working" mean no redirect?

Comment: exactly! I want page to redirect to another page ,but it stays at same page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you replaced the web.config which you are using locally to your server
if not/ not possible
check this below tag

```
<sessionState mode="[Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer|Custom]" 
  timeout="number of minutes">
</sessionState>
```

also Check this get reflected in IIS State management.

Comment: I am using this setting in web.config file.<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <sessionState mode="InProc"
                    cookieless="true"
                    timeout="20"/>
      </sessionState>
   </system.web> it fine??
</configuration>

Comment: :(...yep! .still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You might be using a web garden on the production IIS together with an in-proc session. This means that IIS is spawning multiple working processes on your server.

Therefore each request may be processed by *any* worker process, but an in-proc session is only available within the same process.

You might reduce the number of worker processes to one. However, as spender commented, you should not make your own authentication system.

Comment: exactly! I want page to redirect to another page ,but it stays at same page

Comment: Did this answer (or any other) help you yet?

Comment: @konika we need to be briefed ..so that we can try your scenario and give you a exact soln...